# MS Access VBA Sharepoint permission considerations

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, sharepoint-online

we just evaluated a MS Access O365 VBA technology stack with SharePoint Online as database. 
This works like a charm until the point of security considerations: 
all tables are just lists on SharePoint Online - and all of these lists are completely writable via SharePoint Online website to all of the intended users of the MS Access application. This happens because the users are logged in automatically with their O365 user login, no matter which username is given with the database connection string in MS Access.

Now the question is, if there are any ideas about hiding the database tables from SharePoint Online Website (maybe hiding the Website itself is also an opportunity)?

Or anyone knows how to implement the usual service user login strategy for the SharePoint Online connection? With one Notebook we could manage this: the first login to the SharePoint Online site on this device happend with the already setup service user and from this time  we can connect with this user when included in database connection string - but only on this one notebook.

Many thanks for your help: Michael

Comment: Eh... So restrict their rights of their O365 user login. The only sort-of problem is that you can't impersonate users because login is automatic. There's no reason that every user needs write rights to all tables. Obviously, could trivially find the site + list name if he has access to the database file.

Comment: I mean this set up sounds atrocious. Doesnt sharepoint have form designer? and then you can call the db and fill the forms dynamically?